# Effect of internal series resistance of solar cell

Tags: solar-cell

[image]

Above is the equivalent circuit of a solar cell with internal series resistance. Also the photo generated current \$I_L\$ is constant.

I want to understand how the load resistance changes the terminal characteristics of the solar cell. This is what I have been able to infer so far -

The terminal current expression can be written as -

\$I=I_L-I_S(exp(\frac{V+IR_s}{V_T})-1)\$

\$I_S\$ is the reverse saturation current of the diode.

Now the open-circuit voltage can be found by putting \$I=0\$.

\$V_{oc}=V_Tln(1+\frac{I_L}{I_S})\$

Similarly the Short circuit current can be found by putting \$V=0\$.

\$I_{sc}=I_L-I_S(exp(\frac{IR_s}{V_T})-1)\$

Clearly, if the series resistance is changed, \$V_{oc}\$ will remain the same but \$I_{sc}\$ goes on decreasing. Is this correct? I understand that for small values of \$R_s\$ there won't be any change in \$I_{sc}\$, but after certain value of \$R_s\$, \$I_{sc}\$ is bound to change. I want to know if this is correct or not. Thanks.

Comment: So, how can you consider the effect of the load resistance if you specify « ignore the load resistance »?

Comment: Yes, I am considering it. But since I'm talking about open circuit voltage and short circuit current, it's value can either be infinity or zero.

Comment: And by ignoring I meant to ignore the 50 ohm value. It's simply \$R_L\$.

Comment: Can you please edit your circuit to clarify how you are labeling the voltages and currents (V, Is, I)?  That would make your equations easier to follow.

Comment: @Selvek Done. Please check now.